# Date format conversion to epoch using gawk ( awk )

Tags: shell-scripting, awk, date, conversion

I want to convert dates in a file to epoch time. A sample csv looks like this:

```
$ cat test.jtl 
2016/09/19 00:31:17.080,238,test1  
2016/09/19 00:31:17.154,322,test2 
22-Sep-2014 10:32:35.012,222,test3
```

I have tried the following , but the result just gets the current date

```
cat test.jtl  | gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {command="date -d \"$1\" +'%s%3N'";command | getline $1;close(command);print}'
```

But this returns only the current date in epoch. I think the $1 ( the first data column , which is a date ) is not being passed in properly. But not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting of the assignment to `command` is stopping expansion of `$1`.

```
cat test.jtl | gawk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {command="date -d \""$1"\" +'%s%3N'";command |getline;close(command);print}'
```

works for me